# How to query a single object to be deleted instead of a whole query list?

Tags: python, django

I am able to delete a users' posts (tweets), but when I do it ends up deleting all of that user's tweets when I only want to delete one at a time, I think it has something to do with the way I am querying the users tweets but I am not sure. I am using Django 1.8.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import tagging
from tagging.registry import register as tagging_
import os


def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('photos', str(instance.user.id), filename)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, verbose_name='Biography')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False, blank=True) #reverse related relations, or through
    theme = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True) 


   def __str__(self):
      return self.bio

class Tweet(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    tweets = models.TextField(max_length=120)
    date = models.DateTimeField()



    def json_feat(self):
     return{
      'title': self.tweets,
     }


def __str__(self):
    return self.tweets

tagging_(Tweet)
```

**views.py**

```
def delete_tweet(request, user_id):
    data = {'You deleted your tweet'}
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user)
    get_users_tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(userprofile=user_profile)
    remove_tweet = get_users_tweets.delete()
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

**template**

```
   {% for tweets in tweet %}
     {{ tweets.userprofile.user }} | {{ tweets }} | {{ tweets.date }} | <a href='{% url 'delete_tweet' user_id=user.id %}'>Delete </a> <br />
   {% endfor %}
```

**url**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<user_id>[\d]+)/$', views.delete_tweet, name='delete_tweet'),
```

Comment: You're not passing any information to identify which tweet the user wants to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_users_tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(userprofile=user_profile)
```

Will give you all the tweets written by the specified user -> all of them are deleted. Which one do you want to delete? You need to specify that.

**EDIT:**

*(after specifying what the OP wants to do in the comments)*

Update your **url** to:

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<tweet_id>[\d]+)/$', views.delete_tweet, name='delete_tweet'),
```

...and your **views.py** to:

```
def delete_tweet(request, tweet_id):
    data = {'You deleted your tweet.'}
    tweet = Tweet.objects.filter(pk=tweet_id)
    tweet.delete()
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: How would I go about specifying that? That is what I need to know?

Comment: @appa_lover You need to tell us which tweet you want to delete. We can then tell you how to do that. Do you want to delete e.g. the most recent tweet?

Comment: I have a list of all the users tweets on a page I want to be able to click next to that tweet, and it delete that specific tweet, does that help? Or do you need like a specific object_id?

Comment: Add tweet ID into tweet remove URL and query user tweets by that ID.

Comment: so you saying add tweet_id into my URL, and then from there query each id, so they can be deleted individually?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add tweet id in your URL

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<user_id>[\d]+)/(?P<tweet_id>[\d]+)$', views.delete_tweet, name='delete_tweet'),
```

Then your view will look like this

```
def delete_tweet(request, user_id,tweet_id):
    data = {'You deleted your tweet'}
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user)
    get_users_tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(userprofile_id=user_id,id=tweet_id)
    remove_tweet = get_users_tweets.delete()
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

This will remove that particular tweet regarding that user.